# Как вынести массив javascript во внешний json и потом подключить?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, ini

Подскажите пожалуйста как вынести массив javascript одного файла во внешний файл json или ini, а потом подключить его к первому файлу и вывести.
Массивов может быть несколько.

```
const aaa = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
const bbb = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
```

Comment: Как "вынести" - `fs.writeFileSync('filename.json', JSON.stringify(aaa));`. Как подключить и вывести - уже есть ответ.

Comment: короткий ответ: никак. клиентская часть не имеет доступ к файловой системе на сервере. однако это файл можно захостить на том же веб-сервере и загрузить, например через jQuery (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) или через <script type="text/javascript" src="file.json"></script>

Comment: именно нужно на javascript

Comment: я попробовал использовать fetch

Comment: подойдет любой ajax по вашему выбору: fetch, XMLHttpRequest, jQuery.ajax. если fetch не получился, напишите в вопрос ваш код. народ поможет его запустить.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript:**

```
import array from './arrays.json'

const print = (data) => console.log(data)

array.map(el => print(el))
```

**arrays.json**

```
[
    {
        "aaa": [
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
        ]
    },
    {
        "bbb": [
            "Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Mar",
            "Apr",
            "May",
            "Jun",
            "Jul",
            "Aug",
            "Sep",
            "Oct",
            "Nov",
            "Dec"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Наверное, сначала нужно экспортировать)

Comment: не получается. Нет, экспортировать не надо. Данный массив должен изначально лежать в json и уже потом выводиться в javascript.

Comment: просто сейчас данный массив лежит в javascript в виде как указан выше

Comment: @РустемМукминов обновил пример

Comment: вижу =) только не пойму как мне его в javascript получить в отдельные массивы.